# Subtraction of Frames : OPEN CV:

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am stuck up on an error while capturing the difference of two frames :

```
for(;;)
{   
    colourImage = cvQueryFrame(input);
    diff=cvCloneImage(colourImage);
    colourImage=cvQueryFrame(input);
    cvAbsDiff(colourImage,diff,subtract);
    cvCvtColor(subtract,greyImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cvShowImage("bg subtracted ",greyImage);
    cvThreshold(greyImage, greyImage, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cvDilate(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 18);
    cvErode(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 10);
    cvShowImage("final",greyImage);
    cvWaitKey(33);
    :
    followed to contour extraction.
}
```

After displaying the "final" window , the program terminates without going to the contour section.
The following error is being displayed :

```
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src1.size == dst.size && src1.type() == dst.type()) in cvAbsDiff, file /home/ukri/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 2786,terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' , what():  /home/ukri/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:2786: error: (-215) src1.size == dst.size && src1.type() == dst.type() in function cvAbsDiff.AbortedOpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src1.size == dst.size && src1.type() == dst.type()) in cvAbsDiff, file /home/ukri/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 2786terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'  what():  /home/ukri/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:2786: error: (-215) src1.size == dst.size && src1.type() == dst.type() in function cvAbsDiff.Aborted
```

I made the image type of colourImage , diff and subtract the same. Still the error keeps on recurring.

Comment: If the types are identical the problem is with the matrix sizes. Have you checked on that?

Comment: The included code must always be sufficient to show the problem, yours isn't. Where is the definition of `subtract` ?

Comment: `code` IplImage* greyImage = cvCreateImage( imgSize,IPL_DEPTH_8U,   1); IplImage* colourImage=cvCreateImage(imgSize,IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
 IplImage*diff=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(colourImage),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);IplImage*subtract=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(colourImage),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3); // definition of subtract          `